# Can I create a pointer to poll a float from any source?

Tags: c#, pointers, unity-game-engine, unsafe

Is there a way to access all the different types of object inherited from the same class using the same reference in an object without hard-coding it?

I'm developing on unity and I want to add a module in my game that could watch any particular float in a GameObject to then change another float in another GameObject once it reaches a certain value.

As an example: A "Trigger" Object/Module which set the value of Hunger=1 in a brain Object when the value of Fullness<0.5 is reached in a stomach Object.

As I'll have a big number of possible combinations I don't want to hardcode it by creating a daughter of the Trigger Class for each of them.

My initial idea was to use pointers that would be directed to the good floats to watch/change upon initialization. But apparently, we can't use unsafe code inside iterators (IEnumerator) so I'm not sure how to poll the value of Fullness.

To give an example of what I would like :

```
public Class Trigger{
    private float* ToPoll;
    private float* ToChange;

    public void SetTrigger(float* poll, float* change){
        ToPoll = poll;
        ToChange = change;

        // the loop would be a IEnumerator, not a litteral loop
        while(*ToPoll < 0.5f){
            sleep(0.1)
        }
        *ToChange = 1f
    }
}

void Main(){
    Trigger trigger1, trigger2;
    trigger1.SetTrigger(&Stomach.fullness, &Brain.hunger)
    trigger2.SetTrigger(&Sun.activityLevel, &Earth.radiationLevel)
    // ^ Literally any float from any object
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to or better ways to implement it?

Comment: You can't "poll any float from any object" in this way. You *might* have been able to hack together something like that in C++ using pointer arithmetic, but that kind of thing in C# makes developers shudder: it breaks type safety, garbage collection, and your IDE's ability to tell that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there any way to do something similar ? Not necessarily with pointers? Maybe references or something like that ?

Comment: You want a reference to an object, you need to get it from somewhere that already has it.

Comment: How would you do that In a way that would make it work like I want ? Can you copy the reference ?

Comment: You know how method parameters work, right? Pass the object containing the float to a function.

Comment: I don't see how that fit my needs :/ I need it to be able to target any float in an object without hard-coding it.

Comment: Any field in an object? Reflection.

Comment: Not sure I understand ? 
Could you give me an example as an answer ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958803/finding-all-properties-and-subproperties-of-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the answer from @kara, the following code implements independent `Stomach` and `Brain` objects, and uses `Being` to wire them up.

What `Being` knows about `Stomach`:

- it has a `NeedsFoodEvent`

What `Being` knows about `Brain`

- there is a `OnRaiseIsHungryEvent` (i.e. a "hungry" signal -- who cares where it came from)
- it has a `IsHungryEvent`

Keep in mind that in a real implementation there would likely be other objects listening for those events. e.g. maybe you have an emotion system that would switch to "hangry" and a goal-based AI that would switch to food-seeking mode. Neither system would need to be aware of the other, but both could respond to signals from the `Brain`. In this trivial implementation the `Being` responds to the `Stomach` signal and both notifies and responds to the `Brain`.

The important take-away from this is not the specific method of raising and responding to events (in this case the default .Net mechanism) but the fact that neither object knows anything about the internals of the other (see the different implementations of `HumanStomach` and `ZombieStomach`) and instead the connection is wired up at a more appropriate level (`Being` in this case). Also note the reliance on interfaces, which allows us to do things like create hybrid beings (i.e. pairing a `ZombieBrain` with a `HumanStomach`).

Code was written/tested with .Net Core CLI as a console app, but it should be compatible with most any version of .Net > 3.5.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace so_example
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person1 = new Being("Human 1", new HumanBrain(), new HumanStomach());
            var zombie1 = new Being("Zombie 1", new ZombieBrain(), new ZombieStomach());
            var hybrid1 = new Being("Hybrid 1", new ZombieBrain(), new HumanStomach());
            var hybrid2 = new Being("Hybrid 2", new HumanBrain(), new ZombieStomach());

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class HungryEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IStomach
    {
        event EventHandler<HungryEventArgs> NeedsFoodEvent;
    }

    public class Stomach : IStomach
    {
        public event EventHandler<HungryEventArgs> NeedsFoodEvent;

        protected virtual void OnRaiseNeedsFoodEvent(HungryEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<HungryEventArgs> handler = NeedsFoodEvent;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class HumanStomach : Stomach
    {
        private Timer _hungerTimer;

        public HumanStomach()
        {
            _hungerTimer = new Timer(o =>
            {
                // only trigger if breakfast, lunch or dinner (24h notation)
                if (new [] { 8, 13, 19 }.Any(t => t == DateTime.Now.Hour))
                {
                    OnRaiseNeedsFoodEvent(new HungryEventArgs { Message = "I'm empty!" });
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It's not mealtime");
                }
            }, null, 1000, 1000);
        }
    }

    public class ZombieStomach : Stomach
    {
        private Timer _hungerTimer;

        public ZombieStomach()
        {
            _hungerTimer = new Timer(o =>
            {
                OnRaiseNeedsFoodEvent(new HungryEventArgs { Message = "Need brains in stomach!" });
            }, null, 1000, 1000);
        }
    }

    public interface IBrain
    {
        event EventHandler<HungryEventArgs> IsHungryEvent;
        void OnRaiseIsHungryEvent();
    }

    public class Brain : IBrain
    {
        public event EventHandler<HungryEventArgs> IsHungryEvent;
        protected string _hungryMessage;

        public void OnRaiseIsHungryEvent()
        {
            EventHandler<HungryEventArgs> handler = IsHungryEvent;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new HungryEventArgs
                {
                Message = _hungryMessage
                };

                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class HumanBrain : Brain
    {
        public HumanBrain()
        {
            _hungryMessage = "Need food!";
        }
    }

    public class ZombieBrain : Brain
    {
        public ZombieBrain()
        {
            _hungryMessage = "Braaaaaains!";
        }
    }

    public class Being
    {
        protected readonly IBrain _brain;
        protected readonly IStomach _stomach;
        private readonly string _name;

        public Being(string name, IBrain brain, IStomach stomach)
        {
            _stomach = stomach;
            _brain = brain;
            _name = name;

            _stomach.NeedsFoodEvent += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{_name}: {e.Message}");
                _brain.OnRaiseIsHungryEvent();
            };

            _brain.IsHungryEvent += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{_name}: {e.Message}");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

### Some Notes

To provide some output, I faked things in the 2 `IStomach` implementations. The `HumanStomach` creates a timer callback in the constructor which fires every 1 second and checks if the current hour is a meal hour. If it is, it raises the `NeedsFoodEvent`. The `ZombieStomach` also uses a callback every 1 second, but it just fires the `NeedsFoodEvent` every time. In a real Unity implementation you'd likely trigger the even based on some event from Unity -- an action the player took, after some preset amount of time, etc.

Comment: Awesome! While I will have to study your code a bit more to fully understand it I think it's my best bet. Thanks a lot.

Do you know a way to make this versatile without coding an Eventhanlder for each of them and so the Even can be attached to any variable ?

Also can you direct me where in your code you check the value of let's say stomach fullness so I can start working out through your code ? Or is it not specified and I should learn more about Events to understand this ?

Thank you Again

Comment: Take a look in the constructor for `HumanStomach` at the timer callback (also see the notes in the edited answer) to see how I'm generating the events. You may want to provide a public method on your `Stomach` implementation to allow it to be easily triggered by external code. You would check whatever variables in that method. You really want to get away from thinking about monitoring internal variables directly and instead think in terms of advertising intents.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to do, but it sounds like you want to add triggers to you objects. In my understanding a trigger should be a delegate in this case.

Here an example how to define a delegate-type and add a list of triggers to your Brain-class.

Every brain can now have different triggers. I setup two derived brains to show you how to work with it:

```
public class TestBrain
{
    private static int NextId = 1;
    public TestBrain(List<MyTrigger> triggers)
    {
        this.Triggers = triggers;
        this.Id = NextId++;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int Hunger { get; set; }
    public int StomachFullness { get; set; }
    public List<MyTrigger> Triggers { get; private set; }

    public void FireTriggers()
    {
        foreach (MyTrigger t in this.Triggers)
        {
            t.Invoke(this);
            this.StomachFullness = 100;
        }
    }

    public delegate void MyTrigger(TestBrain b);
}

public class HumanBrain : TestBrain
{
    static readonly List<MyTrigger> defaultHumanTriggers = new List<MyTrigger>()
    {
        b => { if (b.StomachFullness < 50) { b.Hunger = 1; Console.WriteLine("{0} is hungry..", b.Id); } }
    };

    public HumanBrain() : base(defaultHumanTriggers)
    {

    }
}

public class RobotBrain : TestBrain
{
    static readonly List<MyTrigger> defaultRobotTriggers = new List<MyTrigger>()
    {
        b => { if (b.StomachFullness < 50) { Console.WriteLine("{0} ignores hunger only want's some oil..", b.Id); } }
    };

    public RobotBrain() : base(defaultRobotTriggers)
    {

    }
}

static void Main()
{
    // Create some test-data
    List<TestBrain> brains = new List<TestBrain>()
    {
        new HumanBrain(),
        new HumanBrain(),
        new RobotBrain(),
        new HumanBrain(),
    };

    Console.WriteLine(" - - - Output our Testdata - - -");
    foreach (TestBrain b in brains)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Brain {0} - Stomachfulness: {1} Hunger: {2}", b.Id, b.StomachFullness, b.Hunger);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" - - - Empty stomachs - - -");
    foreach (TestBrain b in brains)
    {
        b.StomachFullness = 0;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" - - - Fire triggers - - -");
    foreach (TestBrain b in brains)
    {
        b.FireTriggers();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" - - - Output our Testdata - - -");
    foreach (TestBrain b in brains)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Brain {0} - Stomachfulness: {1} Hunger: {2}", b.Id, b.StomachFullness, b.Hunger);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, impressive. I'm not even sure I have the level to understand your answer ahah.
But maybe to clarify myself so you can tell me if you solution is still valid:
I just want Triggers that can poll any float from any object to then modify any float from any object in an arbitrary manner (meaning there's maybe going to be 1 or 2 Trigger Object at the same time each with one float to poll and one to modify). 

So It could easily use Stomach Fullness to trigger Hunger in the Brain, or vice-versa, or poll a float in the Foot to change a float in the Knee...

Tell me if that makes sense ?

Comment: Unity provides an event system for exactly this sort of cross-object communication that does essentially exactly this. The advantage of using a messaging system is that instead of reaching into a class, the class can advertise its intention (e.g. "I'm Empty!") which can then trigger other intentions (e.g. "I'm Hungry!") without needing to know the specific details. If you think of the public interface of your "objects" (using the term loosely here) as intentions, and keep you implementation private, you'll find your code will be easier to maintain.

Comment: @ColinYoung: Didn't know this - but i'm not realy a unity-expert :). could you provide a answer with an example? I would be interested.

Comment: @kara I'm no Unity expert either. [This example](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system) is a good place to start, as is [this example](http://www.willrmiller.com/?p=87) from Will R. Miller. I'll see what I can do about a specific example though